# Conflict restoring transactions

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement ray wenderlich example: http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial

Purchasing product return me no error at all at the first time.
When I'm trying to restore the purchase I have a response with 0 transactions to restore in method:

`- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue`

Strangely, when I'm trying to buy again same product, I've an alert that I already purchased the item and I can renew or extend.

Why can't I restore the transaction while trying to purchase it again show me otherwise?

```
- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers
{
    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
        }

        // Add self as transaction observer
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];

}

- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    NSLog(@"%s, productIdentifier: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, productIdentifier);

    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product
{
    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

- (void)validateReceiptForTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    VerificationController * verifier = [VerificationController sharedInstance];
    [verifier verifyPurchase:transaction completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        if (success) {
            NSLog(@"Successfully verified receipt!");
            [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to validate receipt.");
            [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
        }
    }];
}

-(int)daysRemainingOnSubscription
{
    NSDate * expiryDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];

    NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"dd MM yyyy"];
    NSTimeInterval timeInt = [[dateformatter dateFromString:[dateformatter stringFromDate:expiryDate]] timeIntervalSinceDate: [dateformatter dateFromString:[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]]]; //Is this too complex and messy?
    int days = timeInt / 60 / 60 / 24;

    if (days >= 0) {
        return days;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

-(NSString *)getExpiryDateString
{
    if ([self daysRemainingOnSubscription] > 0) {
        NSDate *today = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Subscribed! \nExpires: %@ (%i Days)",[dateFormat stringFromDate:today],[self daysRemainingOnSubscription]];
    } else {
        return @"Not Subscribed";
    }
}

-(NSDate *)getExpiryDateForMonths:(int)months
{
    NSDate *originDate;

    if ([self daysRemainingOnSubscription] > 0) {
        originDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
    } else {
        originDate = [NSDate date];
    }
    NSDateComponents *dateComp = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComp setMonth:months];

    return [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComp toDate:originDate options:0];
}

-(void)purchaseSubscriptionWithMonths:(int)months
{
    NSDate *expiryDate = [self getExpiryDateForMonths:months];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:expiryDate forKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    NSLog(@"Subscription Complete!");
}

#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionOBserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased) {
            NSLog(@"transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased");
            [self completeTransaction:transaction];
        }
        else if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored) {
            NSLog(@"transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored");
            [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
        }
        else if (transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed) {
            NSLog(@"transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed");
            [self failedTransaction:transaction];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"None of the above.");
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    NSLog(@"%s, productIdentifier: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, productIdentifier);

    if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.cellularradar.onemonth"]) {
        [self purchaseSubscriptionWithMonths:1];
    }
    else if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.cellularradar.threemonths"]) {
        [self purchaseSubscriptionWithMonths:3];
    }
    else if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.cellularradar.sixmonths"]) {
        [self purchaseSubscriptionWithMonths:6];
    }
    else if ([productIdentifier isEqualToString:@"com.cellularradar.twelvemonths"]) {
        [self purchaseSubscriptionWithMonths:12];
    }

    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification
                                                        object:productIdentifier
                                                      userInfo:nil];
}

- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    NSMutableArray *purchasedItemsIDs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSLog(@"Received restored transaction: %lu", (unsigned long)queue.transactions.count);

    purchasedItemsIDs = [queue.transactions valueForKeyPath:@"payment.productIdentifier"];

    NSLog(@"purchasedItemsIDs: %@", purchasedItemsIDs);

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in queue.transactions) {
        NSString *productID = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
        [purchasedItemsIDs addObject:productID];

        NSLog(@"productID(transaction.payment.productIdentifier): %@", productID);
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%s, %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the message that you received "*Tap buy to renew or extend it*", it seems that your product is a non-renewing subscription. This product type is not restorable by StoreKit API and you must do it yourself (most likely via checking on your server).

A quote from [In-App Purchase Programming Guide (Restoring Purchased Products)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9):

> If your app uses non-renewing subscriptions, your app is responsible for the restoration process.

Here is a comparison of subscription types from In-App Purchase Programming Guide:

```
+------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|   Subscription type    | Auto-renewable |  Non-renewing  |     Free      |
+------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| Users can buy          | Multiple times | Multiple times | Once          |
| Appears in the receipt | Always         | Once           | Always        |
| Synced across devices  | By the system  | By your app    | By the system |
| Restored               | By the system  | By your app    | By the system |
+------------------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: So there is no way to restore it using existing api, right?

Comment: No, as long as non-renewing subscription is what you need. Perhaps you could use a product that is auto-renewable subscription or non-consumable product?

Comment: auto-renewable is best for me but Apple deny using it in Israel and what I need is time based.

Answer (score 1):

In the tutorial you linked to, the last section shows you how you should implement restoring.

Here is the code from that section:

```
- (void)restoreTapped:(id)sender {
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];

    //1
    if ([PFUser currentUser].isAuthenticated) {
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];

        [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:[PFUser currentUser].objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

            //2
            NSDate *serverDate = [[object objectForKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey] lastObject];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:serverDate forKey:kSubscriptionExpirationDateKey];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

            [self.tableView reloadData];

            NSLog(@"Restore Complete!");
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to restore the purchase by checking the receipt data and calculating the subscription accordingly.

As already mentioned it is not possible to restore the transactions as such as they are consumables, however, you can get the receipt and parse this in order to manage restoration / calculations.